# What is the best way to get user with same email address domain in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this function to get the users the same email address domain as the current user. **My question is** Is there a better way to do this in codeigniter ?

My code is

```
<?php
    public function sr_get_identical_users()
    {
        $user_email = substr( $this->session->userdata('email'), strrpos( $this->session->userdata('email'), '@' ) + 1 );
        $this->db->like('email', $user_email, 'before');
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
?>
```

Thanks. Your input is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?  Explaining this might be helpful to answering your question.

Comment: i am making a share function. where the user of the same domain can share his stories with other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the `@` character in your query to find users with the same domain in their email address. If not you will risk getting unwanted matches of multiple different domains. For example the domain `mail.com` will in your query match users with email `name@gmail.com` and `name@hotmail.com` etc..

In your example, you could just remove the `+1` to include the `@`character:

```
<?php
    public function sr_get_identical_users()
    {
        $user_email = substr( $this->session->userdata('email'), strrpos( $this->session->userdata('email'), '@' ));
        $this->db->like('email', $user_email, 'before');
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
?>
```

Maybe you already know that the email address in `session->userdata` is valid, but I would probably validate the email address anyway before performing the query:

```
<?php
    public function sr_get_identical_users()
    {
        $email = $this->session->userdata('email');
        // CHECK IF EMAIL ADDRESS IS VALID
        if (($email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) !== false) {
            $email = substr($email, strrpos($email, '@')); // EXTRACT DOMAIN PART
            $this->db->like('email', $email, 'before');
            $query = $this->db->get('users');
            return $query->result_array();              
        }
    }
?>
```

Also consider security, and avoid selecting all data from the `users` table if it contains sensitive data and hashed passwords etc. Also good practice to only select specific columns for performance reasons if you have a lot of columns in the table not needed for this particular purpose.

Comment: That is a good point about including @. My users will have company emails so this is not highly likely but it is definitely a possibility.